# select in angular2 failed to set the default text

Tags: angular, typescript

This select statement  code failed to set the default text from the component.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Select a Department" [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment"
  (ngModelChange)="onChangeDepartment()" required>
      <option *ngFor="let department of departments"
        [ngValue]="department" [selected]="department.name == selectedDepartment">
        {{department.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

On template, the above code generates.

```
 <nb-select-department _ngcontent-ems-27="" _nghost-ems-28="" ng-reflect-departments="[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-department="Development"><div class="btn-group bootstrap-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn btn-primary btn-round" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" title="Select a Department" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Select a Department</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 162px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height: 162px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">
            Development
          </span><span class="material-icons  check-mark"> done </span></a></li><li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">
            Management
          </span><span class="material-icons  check-mark"> done </span></a></li></ul></div><select _ngcontent-ems-28="" class="selectpicker ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" required="" title="Select a Department" ng-reflect-model="Development" tabindex="-98"><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select a Department</option>
          <!--template bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object]"
    }--><option _ngcontent-ems-28="" value="0: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-selected="true">
            Development
          </option><option _ngcontent-ems-28="" value="1: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">
            Management
          </option>
    </select></div>
    </nb-select-department>
```

You see, the department `Development` is selected by default. But the dropdown shows `Select A Department` as default.

A part of `SelectDepartmentComponent` looks like

```
@Input() departments: any;
  @Input() department: string;
  @Output() done: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  selectedDepartment: string = 'Select A Department';
  value: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedDepartment = this.department || 'Select A Department';
  }
```

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by replacing 4th line of code with `[value]="department.name" [attr.selected]="department.name === selectedDepartment">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ngModel should not be the selectedDepartment, because the selectedDepartment is a string, but array of departments contains array of objects.

Look here:

```
[selected]="department.name == selectedDepartment"
```

It's obvious: department is object

And here you're assigning the string:

```
this.selectedDepartment = this.department || 'Select A Department';
```

Looks like a mess of types and variables

Comment: ya , department is object but `department.name` is a string.

Comment: what I wanted to say is: your data you are working in the Select control is array of objects. After the initialisation of the Select there are Objects, not strings... You should keep to check your code and data with console.log() and google chrome development tools ;)